# Ignore zip error and warning in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I wrote a script that zip all the text file in a given folder.
After the zip the message should be logged into a log file to see what has been zipped.

I am getting the following message:

```
zip warning: name not matched: *.txt

zip error: Nothing to do! (info.zip)
```

I want to ignore this message so I added

```
./archiveAllFiles.sh >> /home/userName/bin/logs/info.txt 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

in my shell script. However, the above would just ignore everything including what is being inflated.
It would not print out anything.....no error, no warning and no information about what has been zipped.

What I want is what are being logged but only excluding the error and warnings.

```
Archive:  info.zip
  inflating: contact.txt
  inflating: data.txt
```

---

Example:

exeAll.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/userName/bin
echo "`date +%\Y-\%m-\%d_\%H:\%M:\%S` -----" >> /home/userName/bin/logs/info.txt;

./archiveAllFiles.sh >> /home/userName/bin/logs/info.txt 2>&1 >/dev/null;
```

archiveAll.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date+ "%Y-%m-%d")
path=/home/system/xminfo

cd $path/xfer/env/data
zip -r $path/xfer/env/data/archive/$date.zip *.txt


cd $path/xfer/db/data
zip -r $path/xfer/db/data/archive/$date.zip *.txt
```

---

If i dont use `2>&1 > /dev/null` I would get

```
zip warning: name not matched: *.txt
zip error: nothing to do! (2017-10-18.zip) <-- comes from path/xfer/env/data
    Archive:  2017-10-18.zip               <-- comes from path/xfer/db/data
      inflating: contact.txt
  inflating: data.txt
```

Because the directory sometimes can be empty.

---

but I just want this part to be logged

```
Archive:  2017-10-18.zip
  inflating: contact.txt
  inflating: data.txt
```

Comment: show your command and what folder content you're trying to zip

Comment: i use zip -r zipname fileToZip

Comment: You are trying to do a wildcard matching in the script `*.txt`, more importantly, did you specify the path name correctly? It seems script not finding the `*.txt` files, try to specify the path.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get it but can't you just redirect the error output ? (`2>/dev/null`)

Comment: @rakib yes, the directory can be empty when the script is executed.If the directory is empty I want to skip the error and just print the directory that has the files and log what was zipped in the logs.

Comment: @Zermingore I tried it but it would still print the error when i used 2>/dev/null that's why i used 2>&1 > /dev/null instead but then this would just ignore everything

Comment: warning can be ignored by passing `-q` option but maybe you can't ignore the error. So, I think it's better if you check to see if the file exist and then try to zip.

Comment: See here for a way to check whether the directory is empty in a script: https://superuser.com/questions/352289/bash-scripting-test-for-empty-directory#352290. I have a nasty feeling that the Linux version on  `unzip` sends both success and failure messages to std out, so trying to redirect stderr won't do much. Perhaps you could pipe the output of `zip` into grep and look for particular patterns that you want logged?